# Old black & white movie with an ostrich-like monster

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, soft-sci-fi

I am trying to find the name of a movie I saw many years ago. Should be from the '50s or '60s, since I remember it was black & white.

The creatures looked like "ostriches", but had some "shell" on their bodies. The back looked like a leaf and on the "belly" looked like a turtle shell shape.

The other thing I remember is that they fall from sky and they killed with a touch (like poison or something similar).

This is all I remember. Does anyone know what this is? I just want to confirm it was not a nightmare.

[image]

This is kind of the image I have in my head. And I found something similar in *[The Giant Claw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giant_Claw)* (1957), but this one has wings and is a giant.
The ones I am talking about are more “human sized”; no wings or arms, only four legs.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: Could you sketch this monster. I'm having real trouble picturing what you're trying to describe.

Comment: Vaguely remindful of the, excuse my french, "Ass Blasters" from Tremors III, who at least have powerful legs and wings that could make you think of leaves. But they are not b/w and do not kill with poison (https://tremors.fandom.com/wiki/Ass_Blaster).

Comment: [This is kind of the image I have on my head.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPytw.jpg) And I found something like the giant claw but this one have wings and is giant.
The ones I am talking about are more “human size” no wings or arms only 4 legs. Thank you everyone

Comment: @IBennetts It appears you've registered a second account, and are now unable to edit your original question, since that was posted with the first account. Please follow the instructions given in [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and merge the two accounts, so you can edit the question or post comments beneath it if you want to. This will also allow you to [accept](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) a correct answer if one is submitted.

Answer (score 8):

I wonder if you're remembering the silicates from *Island of Terror*?
[image]

Details which fit the description:

- With the long tentacle up front they look vaguely ostrich-like, with a "shell" body.
- They do kill with a touch (injecting a bone-dissolving enzyme, according to [the Universal Monsters wiki](https://universalmonsters.fandom.com/wiki/Island_of_Terror) ).

What doesn't fit:

- The monsters in the film don't have legs.
- Every version of this I've seen is in color, not black-and-white. I don't know if the original was b&w.

[A clip of the monsters in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QWCW65--gc)

Comment: Even if it's not right, it's still a great effort.

Comment: i was thinking this even though i had no idea of its title -- but this or a Triffid is what came to mind.

Answer (score 3):

It could be [*Gamera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamera)

[image]

[image]

> Gamera (Japanese: ガメラ, Hepburn: Gamera) is a fictional monster
> originating from a series of Japanese films of the same name. Gamera
> first appeared in Noriaki Yuasa's 1965 film Gamera, the Giant Monster,
> produced by Daiei Film. The character and the first film were intended
> to compete with the success of Toho's Godzilla film series. Since
> then, Gamera has become a Japanese icon in his own right, appearing in
> a total of 12 films produced by Daiei Film and later Kadokawa Daiei
> Studio, as well as in comic books, manga, anime and video games.
> Gamera has been given various nicknames throughout the history of the
> franchise, including the Friend of All Children and the Guardian of
> the Universe.

[*Poison Claws*](https://godzilla.fandom.com/wiki/Gamera): Gamera can emit poisonous liquid from his claws to stun enemy

[*Flying Gamera*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wXiHI-Ueews&t=47s)
[image]

Comment: Still it is a big monster...

Comment: It's very big. Was there a smaller version at some point?

Comment: Friend of All Children, Guardian of the Universe!

Comment: Gamera is really neat. Gamera is filled with meat.

Comment: One of the few kaiju in history to get their own Usenet group.